# Symfony Doctrine catch connection exception

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony 5 project and I need to instantiate a new (dynamic) class and pass to it a db connection, if exists:

```php
    $var = "name-of-my-connection";
    $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager($var);
```

Not all these classes need a connection, in this case there's no db connection in doctrine.yaml for this specific class. I need to trap this error:
Doctrine ORM Manager named "name-of-my-connection" does not exist.

- How can I do that?
- Can I get the list of the available connections and make my check on that list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trap this error, you could catch the thrown exception. In this case, you should catch the InvalidArgumentException.

```php
try{
   $nonExistentManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('foo');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
   //The foo manager does not exist, do something
   //Redirect ?
}
```

If you are searching the list of available managers, you can use the `getManagers` method. This will return an array list of managers. The keys of this array are the available names:

```php
$managers = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagers();
dd($managers);
```

this code returns something like this:

```php
array:1 [▼
  "default" => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#320 …11},
  "foo" => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#321 …12},
  "bar" => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#322 …12}
]
```

Comment: Plead, could you accept this answer, so other contributors won't loose time to read an answered question? Thanks a lot!